# Training segmentation model, 4 GPUs are working, 1 fills and getting: "CUDA error: out of memory"

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I'm trying to build a segmentation model,and I keep getting 
 "CUDA error: out of memory",after ivestigating, I realized that all the 4 GPUs are working but one of them is filling.

Some technical details:

- **My Model:**

  the model is written in pytorch and has 3.8M parameters.
- **My Hardware:**

  I have 4 GPUs with 12GRAM (Titan V) each.

*I'm trying to understand why one of my GPUs is filling up, and what am I doing wrong.*

- **Evidence:**
  as can be seen from the screenshot below, all the GPUs are working, but one of them just keep filling until he gets his limit.

[image]

- **Code:**
  I'll try to explain what I did in the code:

  First my model:

  ```
  model = model.cuda()
  model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=None)
  ```

  Second, Inputs and targets:

  ```
  inputs = inputs.to('cuda')
  masks = masks.to('cuda')
  ```

Those are the lines that working with the GPUs, if I missed something, and you need anything else, please share.

I'm feeling like I'm missing something so basic, that will affect not only this model but also the models in the future, I'll be more than happy for some help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much of the details I can say the following

1. `nvidia-smi` is not the most reliable and up-to-date measurement mechanism
2. the PyTorch GPU allocator does not help either - it will cache blocks of memory artificially blowing up used resources (though it is not an issue here)
3. I believe there is still a "master" GPU which is the one data is loaded to directly (and then broadcast to other GPUs in `DataParallel`)

I don't know enough about PyTorch to reliably answer, but you can definitely check if a single GPU setup works with batch size divided by 4. And perhaps if you can load the model + the batch at one (without processing it).